# How to start/stop Quartz scheduler from database JDBCJobStore

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I tried to stop my Scheduler as follows

```
UPDATE QRTZ_TRIGGERS SET TRIGGER_STATE = 'PAUSED' where TRIGGER_NAME='triggerName'
```

but the scheduler is not stopped and gets triggered at the time specified in the `crone expression.`

so how do i start or stop the quartz from the database ??

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it in two ways. I am not sure whether its a good practice.

1) By deleting the row related to the job from QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS (child table) and from QRTZ_TRIGGERS tables respectively, the job will not execute again. I think we should also delete the row from QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS table as well. But it worked for me even without doing it.

2) In QRTZ_TRIGGERS table, there is a column named END_TIME. If you update it with some specific time (You can use https://www.epochconverter.com/ to get epoch time), quartz is automatically deleting rows from all the 3 tables mentioned above when the time comes.

This solution is for Quartz1. I think it should work in Quartz2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good practice, never use a JobStore directly in youyr code; the results may be unespected.

It is explicitly stated in the [documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09):

> *Never use a JobStore instance directly in your code. For some reason many people attempt to do this. The JobStore is for behind-the-scenes use of Quartz itself. You have to tell Quartz (through configuration) which JobStore to use, but then **you should only work with the Scheduler interface in your code.***